# npm install from private registry with fallback to a git repository URL

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I am kind of a newbie regarding the `npm`, so please help.

Let's say that i have some modules i am working on using a git repository for each one of them and i also installed `sinopia` to have a private registry. The problem is that we are 2 teams. A team in a city and the other one is at world's end. In my team i have installed the private registry to be available in the local network. The issue here is that when we push on git, the other team doesn't have a private registry of their own, and even if they did they would need to publish each version of each module in their private registry. Also another issue is that we can't ( and don't want to ) make the `sinopia` server public via IP.

Now the question is: How can we configure the `package.json` / `npm` to manage dependencies from both the private registry ( if the registry responds ) and the git repository also ( if the private registry doesn't respond -- aka it doesn't exist -- ).

I know that we could set up each dependency to refer to a git tag/branch/commit but we want also to use the registry if possible.

**UPDATE**

So basically I would need a package.json that would know that if this part fails:

```
"dependencies": {
    "app.core": "0.1.1"
}
```

because the private registry is not installed or not available, it could still load the dependecy from something like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "app.core": "git+ssh://git@repo.mydomain.com:group/app-core.git#v0.1.1"
},
```

Also note that i would prefer something that can be pushed in the git repository so that neither one of the teams should change the package.json locally.

Hope that someone can help.

Comment: Multiple registry is not yet done. See [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1401) for help.

Comment: @user568109 Thank you but this is not what i needed. I needed to have a private registry and if that one doesn't exist the dependencies would be installed from a "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/xxx/yyy.git#000" repository

Comment: @user568109 I updated the question to make it more clear what i try to achieve.

Comment: Some packages like npm-delegate and others are mentioned there, which do that (similar to what you asked). Otherwise the maintainers have expressed their inability in doing this right away.

Comment: @user568109 I almost finished everything with all the related links and still haven't found what i was trying to do. I repeat i do not want a fallback registry, but i want a fallback URL if the registry fails. I was just trying the `||` operator from https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#dependencies but with no luck.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get the problem earlier. Try [optional dependencies](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#optionalDependencies).

Comment: @user568109 I tried this: in optionalDependencies i have put the normal registry and in the dependencies i put the git url of the dependency. The problem is that if sinopia ( the private registry is down ) it won't go to install from url.

Comment: Knew that would happen. Try both as optional, or the public one under dependencies and other one optional. I think optional one can override the dependencies.

Comment: @user568109 How should i put them both as optional because both are the same module, the same name. Only fact is that one can be installed from a private registry if available and the other from a git repository that will always be available. In my team i want us to use the private registry while the other team to use the GIT URL to load the  dependencies while we both work on the same modules that are depending one on each other. If you have some time i joined the chat room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that i found to work for the moment is to have a package.json like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall" : "node fallbackDependencies.js"
}
"dependencies": {
    "app.core": "git+ssh://git@repo.mydomain.com:group/app-core.git#v0.1.1"
},
"optionalDependencies": {
    "app.core": "0.1.1"
}
```

And in the `fallbackDependencies.js` file to run a script that takes all the dependencies from the package.json which are also in the `optionalDependencies` and for each of them check if there is a folder with that name in the `node_modules` folder. If there is no folder then run `npm install <json.dependencies[x]>`.

This is the only temporary solution that i could think of.

If someone has a better approach to this please feel free to answer.